# How could I divide a table row into three exact parts?

Tags: android, button, android-tablelayout, spacing

Here is the XML code for the button part for my table row in a table layout:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonclear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonconfirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="18sp"/>

</TableRow>
```

Without inputting constants dip, how could I divide those button evenly into three?
I got no luck in experimenting with the weight though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the `android:stretchColumns` attribute on the TableLayout. As it is zero-based attribute, it should get the value "0,1,2" in your case.

So your XML should probably look as follows:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonclear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear" 
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back" 
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonconfirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirm" 
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but if i would mix it with some of my table row(2columns, 1 textview, 1 edittext) it would mess up bad :(

Comment: Then you need to use the `android:layout_span` attribute on one of the childs of this particular TableRow (the one with 2 columns). It works just like the `colspan` in the HTML.

Comment: i mean i solved this problem by inserting a linearlayout in a tablelayout :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:stretchColumns=*` on yout `TableRow`, and maybe you will also want to set `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on your `TabelRow`.